# Hold hex in an integer without converting it to decimal

Tags: java, android, integer, hex, gson

I have an array of emojis with hex values like this:
`int[] emojis = {0x1F37D, 0x2615...};` and I need to put one of them in a `json` string. something like `{"number":0x1F37D}...`.

I have an object to store the value but the problem is that it keeps changing the hex value to decimal when I assign the hex value in an integer
`object.emoji = emojis[position]`. and then it keeps building the json with the decimal value instead of the hex value I want.

I can't do `Integer.toHexString()` because I need the hex value as a number and not as a string.

In other words: I want this `{"number":0x1F37D}...` and I get this `{"number":3434}...`.

Comment: internal form of number is NOT decimal, hex, octal, binary or whatever. Cat think is 'base 13' or what You want. Base it is ONLY external, printable form for humans

Comment: So how can i store hex number as hex and not decimal?

Comment: You cant hold chars inside an INT

Comment: so how can i hold them in a way that keeps them in a hex form?

Comment: seems like YX problem. What is REAL problem?

Comment: Every decent JSON parser will perfectly understand `{"number":3434}`, but not `{"number":0x1F37D}`. json.org says: "A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used.". So your desired format is something else, not JSON, and you have to write the format generation yourself.

Comment: JSON definition: Octal and hexadecimal formats are not used.

Comment: Who will be consuming this JSON and do they expect hex in particular?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with Gson, or most other JSON libraries because hex literals are not valid JSON.